# Preprocessor variables in VS2017

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2017, wix3

I'm trying to create a new WiX project with Visual Studio 2017 and I'm having a hard time creating a preprocessor variable $(var.buildSrc). In VS 2015 I just went into the project properties and selected the Build tab and created it under "Define preprocessor variables:".

In VS 2017 when I go to properties from my WiX solution all I have available are Project File and Project Folder.

I tried manually adding this into the text of the .wixproj file, but when I try to build the project it still says it can't find my variable.
Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.buildSrc)

The relevant WiX code looks like

```
<File Id=someUniqueID KeyPath=Yes Source="$(var.buildSrc)\somefilename.exe" Guid=someGuid>
```

I'm using WiX 3.11.0.1528 and Rob's WiX tool extension for VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

you can just add it to your main .wxs file, just add the definition of the variable right below the `<wix>` tag:

```
  <?define buildSrc= "c:\mydir?" ?>
```